# Definition of the mapping cone $MC(f)$ for additive category $\mathscr{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be an additive category,then we have category of the complex $C(\mathscr{C})$ which is the full subcategory of the functor category $\text{Func}(\Bbb{Z},\mathscr{C})$.given $f:X\to Y$ be some morphism in category $C(\mathscr{C})$.

We can define the mapping cone as ,with component of the complex ,and differential be：

\begin{aligned}
&\operatorname{Mc}^{n}(f)=(X[1])^{n} \oplus Y^{n}=X^{n+1} \oplus Y^{n} \\
&d_{\mathrm{Mc}(f)}^{n}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
d_{X[1]}^{n} & 0 \\
f^{n+1} & d_{Y}^{n}
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
-d_{X}^{n+1} & 0 \\
f^{n+1} & d_{Y}^{n}
\end{array}\right)
\end{aligned}

Where $d_{\mathrm{Mc}(f)}^{n}(x,y) = (d^{n+1}_X(x),f^{n+1}(x)+d^n_Y(y))$.

The question we do not assume there is addition operation in $Y^n$ correct?why we can define $f^{n+1}(x)+d^n_Y(y)$?

Comment: The notation in the "Where" line seems to suggest you work in some categories of modules, or at least that you're working in a concrete category?

Comment: Yeah thank you Thorgott,the matrix notation for the differential however works in general additive category,under the identification $\begin{aligned}
&\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathscr{C}}(X \oplus Y, U \oplus V) \cong \\
&\qquad \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathscr{C}}(X, U) \times \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathscr{C}}(X, V) \times \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathscr{C}}(Y, U) \times \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathscr{C}}(Y, V)
\end{aligned}$

Comment: I'm aware of the matrix notation, but the notation that you're actually asking about, "$f^{n+1}(x)+d_Y^n(y)$", is written as if you're defining a map on pairs of elements $(x,y)$. If you're working in a category of modules, defining maps by how they act on elements is perfectly fine, but then it's also obvious that you can add elements inside of a module. If you're working in a category that's not a category of modules, you need to explain to me in what sense you're defining a map on elements.

Comment: I understood what you are saying,I just make an additional comment on the matrix notation.And the note I was reading forgot to mention working in category of modules

Comment: If $f\colon X\to Z$ and $g\colon Y\to Z$, this induces a morphism $X\oplus Y\to Z$ by the universal property of the coproduct. It is a common convention to denote this map by $f+g$.